# Click function on external loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some text that is loaded on my site, with the jQuery method load().

I want to close (empty()) the div I've loaded when its h2 is clicked.

My HTML:

```
<html>
   <div class="info_item" id="post1">
      <div name="x" class="item" id="loaded_with_ajax"> 
         <h2>Click on this h2 should empty the div with class="item"</h2>
         <h3>this is a h3</h3> 
         <p>this is a paragraph</p> 
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

My jQuery;

```
$("h2").on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent("div").empty();
});
```

Maybe my code is wrong, but even if I put in a alert() on click h2, on the loaded content, it does not react.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use $(this).parent("div").text("");

Comment: Does not change anything :( It's like the click function is not applied on the loaded content at all..

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/pj4tp/. Call your jquery code in onload or $(document).ready(function(){//Your code});

Comment: @Dineshkani The content is loaded with ajax, so delegation is required

Comment: Your code is not wrong. You should check whether you load jQuery library or not.

Comment: I havde loaded the library and my code is inside $(document).ready(function(){code here..})

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegation:

```
$(".info_item").on('click', "h2", function() {
   $(this).closest(".item").empty();
});
```

I use `closest()` here to make your code more generic.

Comment: This almost works! :) It closes the div, but opens it again within a second..?

Comment: looks like its triggering other handler. Are you sure no other handler could be called by propagation?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question "I want to close (empty()) the div I've loaded when its h2 is clicked" use jquery selector method, get the ID or NAME and [EMPTY](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) or 
jQuery('#parentdivID div').html('');

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('.item').on('click', "h2", function() {
   $(this).parent().empty();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xEsz3/1/)**

Demo loads ajax contents after 3 sec

Comment: does not work. If .item is changed to .info_item it closes the h2, but opens it again within a second.

Comment: @JW_ UPDATED ANSWER WITH demo

Comment: Thanks! I think I need to make some changes in my HTML, before it is going to work as your demo.